# three.js - how to limit the zooming so that object does not break due to camera

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am creating three.js application. I have loaded my STL objects. I have used 'OrbitControls'. When I start zoom my object with middle scroll button of mouse, it breaks at certain point.

My camera and controls code is as below:

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 55, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 15 );
                //camera.position.set( 3, 0.15, 3 );
                // position and point the camera to the center of the scene
                camera.position.x = -3;
                camera.position.y = 4;
                camera.position.z = 5;
                camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera,  renderer.domElement  );
                controls.damping = 0.2;
                //controls.minZoom = 0;
                //              controls.maxZoom = 1;
                //controls .noZoom = true;

                controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );
```

I tried with controls `minZoom` and `maxZoom` but it does not work.

Can anyone please tell me how should I limit the zoom so that beyond certain point my object does not break?

Comment: You can set the camera `near` plane at 0.1 instead of 1.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you are using a `PerspectiveCamera` with `OrbitControls`, you can limit the camera distance like so:

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
controls.minDistance = 10;
controls.maxDistance = 50;
```

Look at the source code `OrbitControls.js` for additional settings.

three.js r.74

Comment: can we do it in trackball controls itself or can we use trackball controls and orbitcontrols together

Comment: Do orthographicTrackballControls has minDistance and maxDistance property?

Comment: And here is the [source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js#L40) for your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

For ReactJs

```
 import { OrbitControls } from '@react-three/drei'
 
 <OrbitControls minDistance={10} maxDistance={50} />
```